# Scaffold repository class from Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scaffolding

I have a Model that is automatically created from a database using entity framework.

This is a project that is just used for data access.

Is it possible to use the scaffolding feature to generate repositories classes for the classes that comes in the model?

I hope that i make myself understood here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have  downloaded the newest [Mvc3 Tools Update](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/03/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) you can follow [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) example.  It will end up creating your controller, views, and repositories.

Comment: The question is when I already have the entity framework model. The classes are created from the model. The problem here is that I cant use the code first aproach since the classes already exist from the entity model.

Comment: You don't need to use the code first approach.  When you go to create your controller it will ask you for your model and DataContext.  If you follow the example it should work for you.  Also, you can do this from the Package Manager console by PM> Scaffold Controller ModelName -Repository -Force